# how to reply back after message queue is completed?

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm adding service bus in my application, in the way that I'll receive a request, and I'll drop a message into a queue, then my microservice will pick that one and do whatever job is needed, and then it will reply back confirming that the original request got completed. But I'm not really sure how to do the last piece...

I was trying to add another queue, so when I receive the original request I'll add to the message a `TicketNumber` and that would be the immediate response, while the complete request it's been processed, once it finishes then drop a message in another queue including that `TicketNumber`, but I've seen I cannot use queues to get an specific message there.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend client has to either use **long polling** or the **Push Api**. You should also consider keeping application state server side for a better user experience.

So after a message is written to the "Completed_Work" que with ticketNumber a Notifier process sends the response back to the client and updates the state on the server. That could also be a K-Table a mongoDb collection or a DB table.

You eather have then client info through applicationKey or use a CorrelationId (stateless mode).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to define a callback protocolo on the mensage. I.e. the message object contains a queue address or an http address that will be used to deliver the executivo result.